# Is there any C# equivalent to Perl's HTML::TableExtract?

Tags: c#, html, perl, html-table

I need to grab a table from a HTML to get the data contained in the table. I've learned from you that it can be solved easily by Perl's [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TableExtract). Since the grabbed data will be showed off by "C#", so if there is C# equivalent to Perl's [HTML::TableExtract](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML::TableExtract), it will easier for me to  implement the whole app.

Comment: The answer is very likely "no". `HTML::TableExtract` is uniquely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codenewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.aspnet.webcontrols/topic8430.aspx

http://mhinze.com/archive/screen-scraping-tutorial-using-c-net/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/weather.aspx

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/529096-how-read-contents-html-table-net

Comment: None of these come close to replicating the functionality of `HTML::TableExtract`. They are way too simplistic compared to what `HTML::TableExtract` does for you.

Comment: Please note that I was only trying to help the gentleman conclude to some solution in C# he could improve on it from these examples,they may be simple but it shows how he could grab a table from a HTML to get the data contained in the table.